# Docker build failing with "failed to compute cache key: "/tmp/mvnrepository.tgz" not found: not found"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am doing a docker build on a Dockerfile and its failing on the below step

```
COPY /tmp/mvnrepository.tgz /opt/mvnrepository.tgz
```

I've tried specifying the file name with docker build -f Dockerfile but I still get the error. I've tried building it from the parent directory with the path to the dockerfile included and the file name like below but i still get the error

```
cd /home/parentdirectory
docker build . -f /childdirectory/Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `/home/parentdirectory` is your docker build context and `/tmp/mvnrepository.tgz`  is not in it. Copy the file in `/home/parentdirectory` then in the Dockerfile change the first arguement of `COPY` accoringly.

`COPY /home/parentdirectory/mvnrepository.tgz /opt/mvnrepository.tgz`